# How to make a Systemd service run forever ("Bootup is not yet finished. Please try again later.")

Tags: systemd, services

I have created a `systemd` service that **has to** run forever (because it does the main job on my embedded computer):

```
# /etc/systemd/system/samplerbox.service
########################################
[Unit]
Description=Starts SamplerBox

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/root/SamplerBox/samplerbox.sh
WorkingDirectory=/root/SamplerBox/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is what it actually does:

```
# /root/SamplerBox/samplerbox.sh
################################
#!/bin/sh
python /root/SamplerBox/samplerbox.py
```

I enabled this service with

```
systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/samplerbox.service
```

**It works, and it is started on boot.**

---

However, since I enabled this service, when I do `systemd-analyze`, I see:

```
Bootup is not yet finished. Please try again later.
```

Moreover, I get this information showing that the service is still seen as "activating" / starting :

```
# systemctl status samplerbox
â samplerbox.service - Starts SamplerBox
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/samplerbox.service; enabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Thu 1970-01-01 00:14:01 UTC; 11min ago
 Main PID: 258 (samplerbox.sh)
   CGroup: /system.slice/samplerbox.service
           ââ258 /bin/sh /root/SamplerBox/samplerbox.sh
           ââ260 python /root/SamplerBox/samplerbox.py
```

**How to properly make a service run forever?**

Answer (score 8):

The solution was quite simple: one has to replace

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
```

by

```
[Service]
Type=simple
```

[This doc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd) states:

> Type=simple (default): systemd considers the service to be started up
>   immediately. The process must not fork. Do not use this type if other
>   services need to be ordered on this service, unless it is socket
>   activated.
>
> ...
>
> Type=oneshot: this is useful for scripts that do a
>   single job and then exit. You may want to set RemainAfterExit=yes as
>   well so that systemd still considers the service as active after the
>   process has exited.